# Rotating a 2D texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to rotate a 2D image about its center point in OpenGL.

Here is my current code:

```
void Plane::draw() {

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, plane_image);                

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (pos.x-6.0, pos.y+6.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (pos.x+6.0, pos.y+6.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (pos.x+6.0, pos.y-6.0);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (pos.x-6.0, pos.y-6.0);
    glEnd ();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

I had to start the quad centered at the origin and then translate it +x,+y. The translation and rotation should go before the quad is created. Thanks to BWG and Skyler!

Solution:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, plane_image);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(pos.x,pos.y,0); 
    glRotatef(45,0,0,1);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (-6.0, 6.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (6.0, 6.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (6.0, -6.0);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (-6.0, -6.0);
    glEnd ();


glPopMatrix();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: In which order is this code executed? Where and when do you bind GL_QUADS?

Comment: If you have depth testing enabled, make sure you have set the depth function to GL_LEQUAL and not GL_LESS.

Comment: I edited it to show the exact order I am trying right now. But I have also tried many other orderings with no luck.


@Nathan I don't think depth testing is enabled.

Comment: So the texture disappears or the entire plane?

Comment: Your final calls to glRotatef and glTranslatef do nothing, because you pop the matrix right after. Try removing your initial call to glTranslatef in the second function.

Comment: Keep in mind that your glTranslate function translates each vertex by `(-pos.x, -pos.y)`. So your vertices become `(pos.x - pos.x +- 6.0, pos.y - pos.y +- 6.0)` ultimately resulting in (+-6.0, +-6.0), making `pos.x` and `pos.y` redundant.

Comment: @Skyler Okay I changed it so the corners are at (-6,-6) and (6,6), then I rotate it 40 degrees, and then translate it +pos.x, +pos.y.

Comment: @BWG I edited the function to take out the redundant rotation and translation. Should I place them before or after I make the quad.

Comment: I changed the translation and rotation to before I made the quad and it works. Solution in original post. Thanks guys!

Comment: You should also be aware that you can rotate textures themselves in fixed-function OpenGL. You could draw your quad the same way and simply manipulate the texture matrix; this matrix literally only rotates/translates/scales texture coordinates and leaves the vertices the way they are.